# Not able to publish messages on rabbitmq to a direct type exchange in spring cloud stream

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I can use Spring Cloud Stream to send and receive message with exchange type of **topic** and **fanout** by producers and consumers, however when I use **direct** it fails, as the configuration below:

```
# consumer configuration

spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: inputA
    stream:
      bindings:
        inputA-in-0:
          destination: exchange1
          group: group1
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          inputA-in-0:
            consumer:
              exchange-type: direct

# producer configuration
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        inputA-out-0:
          destination: exchange1
          group: group1
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          inputA-out-0:
            producer:
              exchange-type: direct
```

The java code:

```
# consumer
@Bean 
public Consumer<List<String>> inputA() {
    return System.out::println;
}

# producer
@Autowired private StreamBridge template;
@RequestMapping("{routingKey}")
public String test(@PathVariable String routingKey, @RequestParam String msg) {
    template.send(routingKey, msg);
    return "send";
}
```

I visit the web page with `localhost:8080/inputA-out-0?msg=1` or `localhost:8080/exchange1?msg=1` with no luck, even though I can the automatically created Exchange `exchange1` and Queue `exchange1.group1`.

However, when I use RabbitMQ management web panel to send message in **Queue exchange1.group1**, the consumer can normally receive the messages, I stop the consumer app, send a message through web panel and then get it directly, it outputs the NACK message content like this:

```
Exchange    (AMQP default) # why???
Routing Key exchange1.group1
Redelivered ○
Properties  delivery_mode:  1   
Payload 12345
...
```

Why the exchange is **AMQP default** instead of the automatically created by spring cloud named **
exchange1**, what's wrong? Help and thanks very much!

Comment: I have used RabbitTemplate instead of StreamBridge to use direct type message queue.